# Remove all numbers except for the ones combined to string using python regex

Tags: python, regex, string, text, text-files

Trying to use a regex function to remove a word, whitespaces, special characters and numbers but not the one combined with to a word/string. E.g.

```
ORIGIN
    1 malwmrllp1 lallalwgpd paaafvnghl cgshlvealy lvcgergffy tpktrreaed
    61 lqvgqvelgg gpgagslqpl alegslqkrg iveqcctsic slyqlenycn

//
```

The \W+ removes all numbers including 1 in malwmrll1

```
import re

text_file = open('mytext.txt').read()
new_txt = re.sub('[\\b\\d+\\b\s*$+\sORIGIN$\W+]', '', text_file)

print(new_txt, len(new_txt))
```

My output is:

```
malwmrllplallalwgpdpaaafvnghlcgshlvealylvcgergffytpktrreaedlqvgqvelgggpgagslqplalegslqkrgiveqcctsicslyqlenycn 109
```

The desired output should be:   `malwmrll1plallalwgpdpaaafvnghlcgshlvealylvcgergffytpktrreaedlqvgqvelgggpgagslqplalegslqkrgiveqcctsicslyqlenycn 110`

Comment: @JvdV the 110 is the character count / length from len()

Comment: @mickeywise, right I overlooked that in the `print()` section.

Comment: Do you have to use RE for any particular reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, depending on your desired result showing underscores at all or not, try to use `re.findall` and raw-string notation. You currently use a character class that makes no sense:

---

```
\b(?!(?:ORIGIN|[_\d]+)\b)\w+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/y54XCY/1)

---

- `\b` - Word-boundary;
- `(?!(?:ORIGIN|[_\d]+)\b)` - Negative lookahead with nested non-capture group to match either `ORIGIN` or 1+ underscore/digit combinations before a trailing word-boundary;
- `\w+` - 1+ word-characters.

---

```
import re
  
text_file = """ORIGIN
    1 malwmrllp1 lallalwgpd paaafvnghl cgshlvealy lvcgergffy tpktrreaed
    61 lqvgqvelgg gpgagslqpl alegslqkrg iveqcctsic slyqlenycn

//"""

new_txt=''.join(re.findall(r'\b(?!(?:ORIGIN|[_\d]+)\b)\w+', text_file))    
print(new_txt, len(new_txt))
```

Prints:

```
malwmrllp1lallalwgpdpaaafvnghlcgshlvealylvcgergffytpktrreaedlqvgqvelgggpgagslqplalegslqkrgiveqcctsicslyqlenycn 110
```

Answer (score 1):

Using RE for this is an interesting academic exercise but extending the functionality is fraught with danger unless one is very familiar with the technique.

This answer may look long-winded but you should be able to see how easy it would be to extend it so that other tokens/patterns can be excluded or included. It's also readily maintainable because anyone else having to modify the code isn't going to get a migraine while trying to figure out how the RE works.

```
FILENAME = 'mytext.txt'

def keep(t):
    if t.isdigit() or t == 'ORIGIN' or t == '//':
        return False
    return True

with open(FILENAME) as f:
    new_txt = ''.join(filter(keep, f.read().split()))
    print(new_txt, len(new_txt))
```

**Output:**

```
malwmrllp1lallalwgpdpaaafvnghlcgshlvealylvcgergffytpktrreaedlqvgqvelgggpgagslqplalegslqkrgiveqcctsicslyqlenycn 110
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

```
new_txt = re.sub('[\\W_]+|\\b(?:\\d+|ORIGIN)\\b', '', text_file)
```

Strip out all *non word characters* + underscore OR digits / "ORIGIN" between *word boundaries*.

[See this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##PY9Ba8MwDIXv/hW6JaHdoAx2GIwdRy8b7LLDPILrKIqp4iqO59TQ/555dJt4AumBPp4kx@Hk724kS15XN8opRAioVMRzbHvHCI9Qvb7tn/cv2kOpHYyGlzEwyw7YcNFC0oEYY/rkaWCwNA@c0HAGTpYwUN9niHKMIaDB7gq6L@dToikhEwEJGZp5EgbD@DMdA4FLOFkbZ2dh5jwx@mx9pTwubTzHEi3g7fx1qKsPrd/bz81F60P99KB1t7lcQzfFqbZQlf5/qVFKgvOx/uVsoYD/lqZZ128) (the regex is very basic, [explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vEI7lW/1))